# Full table search and data encryption

Tags: mysql, vb6, encryption

I had developing a client software in vb6 and mysql. This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main_table` (
    `f_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id` mediumint(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `text_to_encrypt` mediumtext
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `f_id` (`f_id`)
);
```

The client wants that the data to be encrypt the column of text_to_encrypt. Now it is very easy to encrypt the data but the real problem is that it would be fully text searchable to the keywords provided by the user and show the data after decrypting the encrypted data. The column has about 900,000 and going to increase, I want the solution for Windows OS. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

If the client is the one who determines **HOW** something should behave, then the client **HAS** to know that the you cannot search encrypted data with keywords without decrypting it.

That means taking the entire contents of the table, decrypting it and then searching.

Comment: Yes know that but if I decrypt the table every time and then search and then drop the decrypted table would take much time as decrypting large records in short time is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider encrypting and indexing all of the text content on which to make the search. If the text is "Hello world!" you'd save encrypted "hello" and "world" and then search against those, which have been mapped to the encrypted text field upon writing the initial record.

Comment: Assuming there is no rolling encryption, salt or similar, making it a very weak encryption. Every individual word would have to encrypt to the same string every time, meaning it's little more than a ROT encryption.

Comment: That's a fair point. And what of something like this, using salt? We're having a similar issue as OP is having and am considering a method like what I proposed. Below is alg for encrypting strings on the way in:

$salt = self::getSalt();
$string = trim($string);
$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $salt, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
return bin2hex($encrypted); 

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to search an encrypted COLUMN.

If the requirement is simply to encrypt the data, have you considered [Transparent Database Encryption (TDE)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)?